# I get strange output when i use var keyword in for loop with setTimeOut inside

Tags: javascript

I have this code.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I don't understand the output from this lines of code:
The output in the console is number 6,and it says that is repeated five times.
If i use the let keyword for "i" then i get the output that i expect,
1,2,3,4,5 after one second
Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

`var` has scoping issues and that's why `let` was introduced.

In your for loop you are defining `i`, but actually it's stuck to the global scope, and after 1 second, the for loop would actually be done, and when the setTimeout callback is fired, `i` would have already reached 6 and it's read from the global scope.

In a nutshell, because `i` is stuck to the upper scope of `for`, each iteration modifies the calue of `i` and doesn't create another `i`.

If you change `var` to `let`, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is async hence will execute after the loop is done, that s why you have i=6, put it in a self invoking function to retain the value of i or use let instead of var in your loop

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  ((i) => setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000))(i)
}
```

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```